# How to count joining tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 4 tables Joining the other is joined through markets and I need help to produce total records from each table, the tables are as follows...

```sql
councils
------------------------
| council_id  | name   |
------------------------
|    1        |   c1   |
+-------------+--------+
|    1        |   c2   |
------------------------


Markets
----------------------------------
| market_id | council_id | name  |
+-----------+------------+-------+
|   1       |    1       | wells |
+-----------+------------+-------+
|   2       |    1       | John  |
+-----------+------------+-------+
|   3       |    2       | abcd  |
----------------------------------

Marketeers
-------------------------------------
| marketeer_id | market_id  | name  |
+--------------+------------+-------+
|   1          |    2       | a     |
+--------------+------------+-------+
|   2          |    3       | b     |
+--------------+------------+-------+
|   3          |    1       | c     |
-------------------------------------

Stations
----------------------------------
| station_id | council_id | name  |
+------------+------------+-------+
|   1        |    1       | x     |
+------------+------------+-------+
|   2        |    2       | y     |
+------------+------------+-------+
|   3        |    2       | z     |
-----------------------------------

SELECT 
    c.council_name, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT market_id) AS num_markets, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT station_id) AS num_stations, 
    COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) AS num_markteers
FROM markets m
JOIN councils c ON m.council_id = c.council_id
LEFT JOIN stations s ON s.council_id = c.council_id
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT m2.council_id, COUNT(DISTINCT marketeer_id) AS cnt
    FROM marketeers p 
    JOIN markets m2  ON m2.market_id= p.market_id
    GROUP BY m2.council_id
)t2 USING (c.council_id)
GROUP BY c.council_id;
```

> ERROR :Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '.council_id) GROUP BY
> c.council_id' at line 10

Expected Result

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| council_name | num_markets | num_stations | num_markteers |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|    c1        |   2         |    1         |    2          |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|    c2        |   1         |    2         |    1          |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please add the query

Comment: The error message points you to `... )t2 USING (c.council_id) ...`. In the USING expression you must specify column names only, without table alias - because specified column names will be searched in all tables/subqueries which are visible in this point of FROM clause. Hence server thinks that `c` is column name and `.council_id` is errorneously added chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT c.council_name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT market_id) AS num_markets, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT station_id) AS num_stations, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT marketeer_id) AS num_markteers
FROM councils c 
join markets m ON m.council_id = c.council_id
left join Marketeers m2 m2.market_id= m.market_id
LEFT JOIN stations s ON s.council_id = c.council_id
GROUP BY m2.council_id,c.council_name
```